# function with nested if blocks not working

Tags: c

Here is my code.  Whenever I enter SAR into the input, the program doesn't print anything for some reason. Shouldn't it go to the first if and then the second if under that and print out "A R S"?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void orders_char(int c1, int c2, int c3);

void orders_char(int c1, int c2, int c3)
{
    if(c1 < c2)
        if(c2 < c3)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c1, c2, c3);
        else if(c3 < c2 && c1 < c3)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c1, c3, c2);
    else if(c2 < c1)
        if(c1 < c3)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c2, c1, c3);
        else if(c3 < c1 && c3 < c2)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c3, c2, c1);
        else if (c3 < c1 && c3 > c2)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c2, c3, c1);
    else if(c1 > c3)
        if (c3 < c2 && c2 > c1)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c3, c1, c2);
        else if(c3 > c2 && c2 < c1)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c2, c3, c1);
        else if( c3 < c2 && c1 > c2)
            printf("Ordered characters are: %c %c %c", c3, c2, c1);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    char c1, c2 ,c3;
    int i = 65;

    printf("Please enter 3 capital letters with no spaces: \n");
    scanf("%c%c%c", &c1, &c2, &c3);
    orders_char(c1, c2, c3);
    return 0;
}
```